# Updating to macOS Sierra from OS X 10.6.8

Tags: snow-leopard, macos, software-update

My OS is 10.6.8.  Yosemite is no longer available in US.  But Sierra needs 10.7 to download. Help! I'm stuck in a loop!

And cannot install my new printer until this is resolved. :/

Answer (score 2):

You can install El Capitan [from the App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/app/os-x-el-capitan/id1147835434?mt=12) (even on 10.6.8) for free, and then update to Sierra after completion.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [buy 10.7 here](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/D6106Z/A/os-x-lion). Upgrade your computer to 10.7 and then download Sierra and install.

EDIT: According to timothymh's answer, you can also install 10.11 for free and then update to Sierra. This is free compared to my solution.